# Python's equivalent to shell find command

Tags: python-3.x

Writing my first Python3 script from a known shell script, and have run into a small issue with the find command and Python equivalent.

There are days of pcap files in a directory. User input defines **start date+time** AND **end date+time**.

This is the command and output used in the shell script. See below the cut command scrubs everything but the file name. The start and end times are variables, so in the example below I have substituted for actual date+time.

```
find /mnt/pcap/captures/ -type f -newermt "08/08 08:00" ! -newermt "08/08 08:02" | cut -c20-40

full_cap_1354

full_cap_1353

full_cap_1348

full_cap_1350

full_cap_1349

full_cap_1352

full_cap_1351
```

I did find a way for Python to run the os find command, but I can't seem to pass the start and end variables into the command.

```
subprocess.check_output('find /mnt/pcap/captures/ -type f -newermt "$date1" ! -newermt "$date2" | cut -c20-40 > /home/mydir/loading_dock/load.txt', shell = True)
```

So, either if there is a way to pass the variable, that is fine OR since I'm learning Python, would like to have a Python way of doing it.

Comment: Have you given a look at the `os` python module? Maybe in its [Files and directories](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) section you could find usefull information

Answer (score 0):

You should pass subprocess a list of strings not only strings

Comment: Any examples of such?

Comment: As you see you are passing to subprocess.check_output() a string!.. You must use insted a List of strings, each element of that list will be a single option/command or whatelse you want on shell that will be separated by a space... for example try:  subprocess.check_output(['find', '/mnt/pcap/captures/',' -type', 'f', '-newermt', '"$date1"', '!', '-newermt', '"$date2"', '|', 'cut', '-c20-40', '>', ''/home/mydir/loading_dock/load.txt'], shell = True)

Comment: Every piece of your command becomes an element of the List.. In that way you can pass dynamic commands to the Shell if the elements of your List are dynamically appended on you script :)